# Running discord bot in a process

Tags: python, discord, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I would like to run a discord in a process. The reason is I have a code which should run as fast as possible, it already works quite well except the discord bot which seems to doesn't start if called from a process.

**The code which works**

*The discord function*

```
def run_discord_bot():
print('load env')   
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=".env")
discord_bot = os.environ.get('discord_bot')
loop = client.loop
discord_task = loop.create_task(client.start(discord_bot))
print(f'start client {client}')
loop.run_until_complete(discord_task)
```

the function works well if I call it within a thread

```
thread = Thread(target=run_discord_bot)
thread.start()
```

but it never starts if I call it in a process

```
results = []

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_procs) as executor:

    results.append(executor.submit(
        function_1
    ))

    results.append(executor.submit(
        run_discord_bot
    ))

    results.append(executor.submit(
        function_2
    ))

    for result in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
        try:
            pass
        except Exception as ex:
            print(str(ex))
            pass
```

I tried several things but nothing works. Any idea ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: don't you get error message when you run it? Threads share variables but processes don't share variables and it has to write it to file (`pickle`) and read in process - but some data can't be send this way (ie, it can't send running `loop`) and it should raise error for this. If you want to run discord in process then better run all code in process - import discord in process, and create bot in process, and use `bot.run()` in process (to run new `loop` in process).

Comment: thank you @furas. You were right, creating the bot in the process seems to make it works ! I will do further tests but it is promising.